# Query: Count Alphabetical wise name

Tags: mysql

I have one `voter` table which contain large amount of data. Like

```
Voter_id  name      age  
1         san       24  
2         dnyani    20  
3         pavan     23   
4         ddanial   19  
5         sam       20   
6         pickso    38
```

I need to show all `voter_name` by Alphabetically and count them.Like

```
 name        
 san  
 sam  
 s...
 s...     
 dnyani  
 ddanial
 d...    
 pavan             
 pickso
 p..
 p..
```

I try using `count(voter_name)` or `GROUP BY`.
But both not working for me..... Suppose table contain 50 voters details.
number of person name start with `A=15,b=2, c=10,y=3` and so on.
Then how to count and show first 15 record of 'A' person, next 2 record of 'B' person and so on..
Give me any reference or hint..
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This order names only:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `voter` ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

This counts each occurrence of the first letter and group them group them together
ex.:

```
Letter  COUNT
------ -------
  A      15
  B      2
  C      10
  y      3

SELECT SUBSTR(`name`,1,1) GRP, COUNT(`name`) FROM `voter` WHERE
SUBSTR(`name`,1,1)=SUBSTR(`name`,1,1) GROUP BY GRP ORDER BY GRP ASC
```

Here you go!

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as this,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,1,1) as ALPHABET, COUNT(name) as COUNT 
FROM voter GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name,1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need names and their counts in ascending order, then you can use:

```
SELECT 
    name, COUNT(*) AS name_count 
FROM 
    voter 
GROUP BY 
    name 
ORDER BY 
    name ASC
```

Which will give the output like

```
name    name_count
------------------
albert          15
baby             6
...
```

If you need to display all records along with their counts, then you may use this:

```
SELECT 
    voter_id, name, age, name_count
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            name, COUNT(name) AS name_count 
        FROM 
            voter 
        GROUP BY 
            name
    ) counts
    JOIN actor 
    USING (name) 
ORDER BY 
    name
```

and you get the output as:

```
voter_id   name     age   name_count
------------------------------------
       6   abraham   26            2
      24   abraham   36            2
       2   albert    19            1
       4   babu      24            4
      15   babu      53            4
      99   babu      28            4
      76   babu      43            4 
...
```

Comment: He wanna count all of the words starts with the A,B,... and group the counts by the letter, already did it, check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `SUBSTRING` function of MySQL here

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring
```

And we can use a sub-query to achieve our result.

So using that, how about this

```
SELECT voter_id, name, age, COUNT(*) AS alphabet 
FROM 
    (SELECT voter_id, name, age, SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) AS first_letter FROM voter) 
AS voter 
GROUP BY first_letter 
ORDER BY first_letter ASC
```